# byte[] is not being nulled after setting it to null

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mariadb, jhipster

I have a project with Hibernate 5.2.17.Final and Java 8 with MariaDB.

My entity has a `byte[]` field where I save a file into the DB. After I used that field to send the file to S3 I want to delete its content (setting it to null) and then save the entity to the DB with that field set to `null`.

I need to keep that column in the db as this is an upgrade and there are entries with a not-null value for that column.

What I've tried:

```java
// first this:
invoiceDTO.setPdf(null);
// as the value of "PDF" is already null, invoice will have it also null
Invoice invoice = invoiceFaMapper.toEntity(invoiceDTO);
invoice = invoiceFaRepository.save(invoice);
```

When debugging the field was null, but the value in the DB is not null.

```
// then I tried this:
byte[] pdf = null;
invoice.setPdf(pdf);
```

which also left me with a not-null value in the db, again, when debugging the `invoice` had a not-null value.

```java
// last thing I tried was:
invoice.setPdf("".getBytes());
```

Again, it wasn't null.

What am I missing?

EDIT: After `invoice = invoiceFaRepository.save(invoice);` this is the value for the `byte[]` field.

[image]

If I'm debugging and taking my time, the field is set to null, if there is no breaking point, it won't be set to null but to the previous value.

I have even tried this after already saving it to make it null, to no avail.

```java
invoice.setPdf(null);
invoiceFaRepository.save(invoice);
```

EDIT2: Invoice.java (relevant)

```java
(...)

@Lob
@Column(name = "pdf")
private byte[] pdf;

(...)

public byte[] getPdf() {
    return pdf;
}

public Invoice pdf(byte[] pdf) {
    this.pdf = pdf;
    return this;
}

public void setPdf(byte[] pdf) {
    this.pdf = pdf;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if you don't get a duplicate in database? One with old value and one with null?

Comment: if you mean the there might be another column in the db, then no, there is only one column holding such value

Comment: Not a column, I mean another record in the table.

Comment: no, I'm creating new entries to check that the value is null or not, none of the new entries are

Comment: Plz paste detail code of `Invoice` class

Comment: added the relevant part of the entity

Comment: ’If I'm debugging and taking my time, the field is set to null ...’ that points to a problem that your changes are not commited to the DB.

Comment: it was actually related to the annotation in the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After saving the object to the DB, I redirect to that object. As an invoice has many lines, I query que invoice and its lines

```java
Optional<InvoiceDTO> invoiceDTO = invoiceService.findOneWithLines(id);
```

Inside that method I had something like this:

```java
    @Override
    public Optional<InvoiceFaDTO> findOneWithLines(long id) {
        Optional<Invoice> i = invoiceFaRepository.findById(id);
        i.ifPresent(invoice -> {
            if (invoice.getAttachmentUrl() != null) {
                invoice.setPdf(amazonService.downloadFile(invoice.getAttachmentUrl()).toByteArray());
            }
        });
        return i.map(invoiceFaMapper::toDto);
    }
```

the thing is that whatever I do inside the brackets gets stored in the DB and I don't know why (I'm not calling the repository, so why would that get saved?).

I solved the issue by editing the field outside the `i.ifPresent(invoice -> {` line.

EDIT: the `Service` class was annotated with `@Transactional`, adding `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` really solved the problem.